# Setting up Zend Framework killed my internet

Tags: frameworks, debian

I am on debian and installing zend framework. I got to the part where you create the virtual host. It never worked for me. And now my internet is down. I've been trying to figure it out and revert all the changes I did. My hostname is back to what it was, I deleted the other entry in the `etc/hosts` file. I can't even ping a website. It says `Cannot connect to hostname` when I try to open a page in the browser. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache virtual host is not effect to your internet connection.
Make sure is correct your internet setting in the machine. (IP/Route)
Restart you network.